# SQL Wildcards to RegExp replace certain text in a column content

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, sql-server-2012

I have got a table where one of the column has text mixed with HTML data. This was due to a bug (fixed) in a script, but the SQL data needs to be edited to reflect the changes. The column has a type `nvarchar(max, null)`. All I need to do is find tags such as `<a img="lkss">`,`<div attr=val>` and replace them with empty string `""`. I looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698747/using-a-wildcard-in-an-update), but the solution says how to replace the entire contents based on one pattern. My problem is that I need to replace contents partly, but preserve clean text (i.e. not HTML tags/attributes). Any suggestion/help is appreciated.

Test column data:

```
<div attr=val; color=somecolor>inside text<div some=val><a some=val>Inside anchor
```

Expected result:

```
inside textInside anchor
```

Comment: I doubt you had a problem with the regex itself (`<[^<>]+>` or `<.*?>`). What tool/language/environment are you using to do this? Please share the code if you have it.

Comment: @stribizhev       I don't have a problem with regex itself, but don't know what the correct regex will be to correct the data mentioned above. I am in SQL Server 2012

Comment: What about [Regex pattern inside SQL Replace function?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23001916/3832970) post? Must be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a CTE like this:

```
DECLARE @str nvarchar(max) = '<div attr=val; color=somecolor>inside text<div some=val><a some=val>Inside anchor';

WITH CTE(myStr) AS (
    SELECT @str
    UNION ALL
    SELECT REPLACE(mystr, SUBSTRING(myStr, CHARINDEX('<', myStr, 1),  CHARINDEX('>', myStr, 1) - CHARINDEX('<', myStr, 1) + 1), '')
    FROM CTE
    WHERE PATINDEX('%<%>%',myStr) > 0
)
SELECT myStr
FROM CTE
WHERE PATINDEX('%<%>%',myStr) = 0
```

I suggest you to use it in a SVF like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION tagRemover 
(
    @str nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ResultVar nvarchar(max);
    SELECT @ResultVar = @str;

    ;WITH CTE(myStr, id) AS (
        SELECT @str, 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT REPLACE(mystr, SUBSTRING(myStr, CHARINDEX('<', myStr, 1),  CHARINDEX('>', myStr, 1) - CHARINDEX('<', myStr, 1) + 1), ''), id + 1
        FROM CTE
        WHERE PATINDEX('%<%>%',myStr) > 0
    )
    SELECT @ResultVar = myStr
    FROM CTE
    WHERE PATINDEX('%<%>%',myStr) = 0;

    RETURN @ResultVar;
END
GO
```